# How can I open several files at once in Vim?

Tags: vim

Is there a way to open all the files in a directory from within Vim? So a `:command` that would say in effect "Open all the files under `/some/path` into buffers".

Ideally, it would be great to open all the files under a dir recursively.

Answer (score 111, accepted):

The command you are looking for is args:

For example:

```
:args /path_to_dir/*
```

will open all files in the directory

Comment: Use `**` to match files recursively. E.g. `:args /path_to_dir/**`

Comment: To open files without an extension, specify the parent directory e.g. args **/.hg/hgrc works but **/hgrc does not.

Comment: Once the files are opened use `:tab all` to put them in individual tabs.

Comment: "All the files" will include sub-directories which may not be desired.  (My vim errors `"/path_to_dir/subdir/" Illegal file name` ).  Quick solution is to run second command `argd */` to remove those from the list again

Comment: It would be really nice to complete the answer with the following suggestion: As a good practice and in order to show how to apply the same set of commands to all files that have been opened, you can execute the following command to apply all the orders contained in my_commands_batch.vim file `:argdo source my_commands_batch.vim`

Comment: Is there a way to do this without changing the active buffer (one that is being edited before calling this)?

Answer (score 22):

Why it doesn't work if I want to open all files ending with a certain extension? 
I tried

```
:n ./**.cs
```

and opens only the files in the currenty directory.

I found the answer.The correct code is `:n **/*.cs`

For more information  `:h find`

Answer (score 9):

Did you try

```
:n /some/path/*
```

It will open all files in /some/path

I don't think it'll open file recursively though.

EDIT

Maybe using ** will open recursively as daf mentionned

Comment: What does the :n means? Looking into vim's help only points me to "repeat the last pattern" .. which I understand is the keystroke. Is there a way to get help for command mode only?

Comment: Too easy :h :n  .. get help for ":n". Don't I like answering my own questions ;)

Answer (score 4):

A method that doesn't require messing with `args` is to put the list of files in a text file, and then use the `:so` command to run the commands in that file.

For example, if you want to open all the files that end in `.php` in a given directory, first create `files.txt` containing the list of files, prepended with whatever command you want to use to open them.

```
sp alpha.php
sp bravo.php
sp charlie.php
```

Then, within vim:

```
:so files.txt
```

If the list of files is large, it's relatively trivial to generate the `files.txt` file quickly, by redirecting the output of `ls` to a file, and then using a vim macro to prepend `sp` before each filename.

This obviously isn't as elegant as using the `args` and `argdo` commands, but those commands are also a lot more complicated.

There also might be a way to do this with a single command on the command line, but even after 16 years I still find vim programming to be strange and arcane.

Comment: Interesting ! Sounds like a good way to keep control over which files are required to open, instead of blindly opening all files of a given directory if these files aren't all required.

Answer (score 1):

Another way to open files recursively

```
find . -type f -exec vi {} \;
```

Comment: Does not meet the restriction “from within Vim”.

Comment: and yet does what is needed :)

Comment: It does not. What is needed is files from the given directory recursively *from within vim*. If you are throwing away conditions you may as well say that `kate **/*(^/)` (using zsh globbing syntax) does what is needed: opens files from the given directory recursively. It is not “from within” and it is not using vim at all, but it “yet does what is needed”. Or even `kate ~/.vimrc ~/.bashrc`. Omitting “from withing”, “from the given directory” and “recursively” altogether, but it “yet does what is needed”: opens files.

Comment: This opens the files one at a time

Answer (score 1):

If you'd like to add to the argument list;

```
:arga what_you-d_like_to_add
```

see

```
:he arga
```

from/in vim for more information.