# Open several files in new tabs with VIM

Tags: vim

How can I open several files using wildcards in a new tab for each file with VIM?

Similar to [How can I open several files at once in Vim?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2023191/how-can-i-open-several-files-at-once-in-vim) but in new tabs instead of buffers.

Comment: It is impossible to open several files and *not* have them been opened in several buffers. Tabs are only viewports, you can of course have number of viewports=number of files and have one file for one viewport but it is simply not what tabs were designed for. None of the vim commands expects you to use tabs in this fashion and thus none of them will help you to preserve “one file per tab” relation.

Comment: Related: [How to get vim to open multiple files into tabs at once](https://superuser.com/q/171763/150178) at Super User.

Comment: Related: [How can I open multiple tabs at once?](https://vi.stackexchange.com/q/2108/16613) at Vim SE.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

If you are in Vim, this command will open each html file in the current directory in its own tab and restore syntax support (disabled by `:argdo`):

```
:args *.html | argdo tabe | tabdo syntax on
```

If you are in your shell, go for the other answers.

Answer (score 35):

Use the `-p` flag:

```
vim -p *.c
```

The above will open all files matching `*.c`.

You can also create an alias for this (I have `alias vip='vim -p'` and I only type `vip *.c` for the above example)

Comment: Maybe because having `vim -p` in alias is very strange? Tabs are not for this. Can’t say for sure though: I did not downvote.

Comment: It's not strange, you can use many aliases and functions to be more productive :)

Comment: I did not mean *using an alias* is strange. I meant *using `-p` in a vim alias* is strange. Tabs are viewports, you don’t need as many viewports as you have buffers.

Comment: Although this works, but it won't open more than 10 tabs unless you modify the `tabpagemax` option (10 is default).

Comment: However, default max number of tabs that can be opened may be limited. Hence you might want to add this (set tabpagemax=100) line to your ~/.vimrc file changing the tab limit as per your requirements.

Comment: I was searching for a setting in the .vimrc for doing this by default, but I guess the alias would do it too. Thanks.

Answer (score 18):

If you want to open only .md.

```
vim -p *.md
```

Or after opening vim, use `:args` to specify md files.

```
:args *.md
:tab all
```

Comment: I prefer the `args` way: If you do `:tab sball` afterwards, the previously opened buffer will also be among the tabs.

Answer (score 8):

with the `p` option: `vim -p file1.cc file2.cc file3.cc`

Answer (score 1):

To open files in new tabs without replacing the arguments or tabs that are already open:

```
:argadd *.c | tab all
```

Also, to search for files in subdirectories:

```
:argadd code/**/*.c | tab all
```