# Is there a :tabnew for multiple files?

Tags: file, vim, tabs

**Edit: This question has answers on vi.SE: [How can I open multiple tabs at once?](https://vi.stackexchange.com/a/2110/852)**

---

The `:tabnew` command can open a file in a new tab in vim. However, it cannot handle multiple filenames:

```
:tabnew file1.h file2.h
```

results in

> E77: Too many file names

Perplexingly, it actually seems to do shell expansion, so `:tabnew *.h` will expand to all files with the ending `.h` in the current directory. But then the command only succeeds if this matches exactly one file.

Is there a way to have the same functionality but open all matching files in a separate tab? Either make `:tabnew` capable of it or have a different command, e.g. `:multitabnew` that does this.

Comment: Vim's view of tabs is that they are for different collections of viewports, rather than for different files (here's [some random blog's explanation](https://joshldavis.com/2014/04/05/vim-tab-madness-buffers-vs-tabs/)). Buffers are how vim expects you to open multiple files, either by passing them on the command line (`vim file1 file2 ./*.txt`) or opening one at a time (`:e file3`) or opening multiple at once (`:arga[dd] ./*.sh`). You can see the buffers you have open with `:ls` and hop between them via number (`:3b`) or partial name (`:b myfi` will find `ThisIsMyFile.txt`).

Comment: @jeremysprofile I understand that, but although I know that I *should* work more with buffers I somehow always fall back to a tabbed setup. I've tried numerous times, but it just doesn't work for me and I prefer using tabs for individual files with the occasional split or vsplit.

Comment: understood. I don't think there's a truly one-line method of doing this, but there were [some decent suggestions on this question on the vi StackExchange](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/2108/how-can-i-open-multiple-tabs-at-once)

Comment: @jeremysprofile I entirely forgot that there was a vi StackExchange. Thanks.

Comment: I think this SO question might actually answer it better than the vi SE. [Open several files in new tabs with VIM](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11430361/open-several-files-in-new-tabs-with-vim)

Comment: The vi.SE question answers this question, the SO one does not, IMO. Unfortunately one cannot close as dupe of a network-question. I've added the link to the question as if it was closed.

Comment: There is an [issue](https://vi.stackexchange.com/q/24390/852) with the answer given in the link.